# Get-ChildItem in Robocopy not working as expected

Tags: command-line, powershell, file-transfer, file-management, robocopy

I'm looking to find all .jpg files in `D:\ZZZ_Phone_test` and its subdirectories and then have Robocopy to copy those to `D:\ZZZ_Phone_test\1\1\BackUp\` (which needs to be excluded because it is within the source)

I'd prefer to use Robocopy if possible instead of scripting something more complex. I'm planning to use Robocopy logging and other options. If it won't go with Robocopy please provide explanation and sources for whatever you come up with.

This doesn't work:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse D:\ZZZ_Phone_test -Exclude D:\ZZZ_Phone_test\1\1\BackUp -filter *.jpg | ForEach-Object {
  robocopy "D:\ZZZ_Phone_test\$_" "D:\ZZZ_Phone_test\1\1\BackUp\$_" /z /s /v
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that familiar with **Robocopy**, but looking at the help, I think this will work for you:

```
$Source = 'D:\ZZZ_Phone_test'
$Backup = 'D:\ZZZ_Phone_test\1\1\BackUp'
Get-ChildItem $Source -Directory -Recurse | ? FullName -ne $Backup | ForEach{
    robocopy $_.FullName $Backup *.jpg /z /v
}
```

Because `Get-ChildItem` is returning a collection of folders, I dropped the `/s` parameter.

If there is only the one folder named `Backup` and you want the paths in code rather than as variables, this should work:

```
Get-ChildItem D:\ZZZ_Phone_test -Directory -Recurse | ? Name -ne 'Backup' | ForEach{
    robocopy $_.FullName D:\ZZZ_Phone_test\1\1\BackUp *.jpg /z /v
}
```

Using **PowerShell** aliases, this can be shortened to:

```
gci D:\ZZZ_Phone_test -ad -r | ? Name -ne 'Backup' | %{
    robocopy $_.FullName D:\ZZZ_Phone_test\1\1\BackUp *.jpg /z /v
}
```

Comment: **Thank you this works as expected.** Although as I found out it's inefficient to do it this way because for each folder that Get-childitem returns, Robocopy would list all the files already in the destination. I think I'll be using Copy-Item instead that supports pipe input.

Comment: `"...Robocopy would list all the files already in the destination."` --- Isn't that due to the `/v` switch? _`"/v Produces verbose output, and shows all skipped files."`_

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\ZZZ_Phone_Test" -Exclude "D:\ZZZ_Phone_test\1\1\BackUp" | 
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.jpg |
    Foreach {
      robocopy $_.fullName "D:\ZZZ_Phone_test\1\1\BackUp" /z /b
    }
```

/z switch is not required because there are no need of copying sub directories.

Comment: it gives an error for each file attempted to be copied:  

  Started : Friday, August 14, 2020 5:23:01
   Source : D:\ZZZ_Phone_test\1\111.jpg\
     Dest : D:\ZZZ_Phone_test\1\1\BackUp\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /B /R:1000000 /W:30


2020/08/14 05:23:01 ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Accessing Source Directory D:\ZZZ_Phone_test\1\111.jpg\
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.